# What are the differences between \newdimen, \newskip and \newlength?

Tags: macros, lengths, dimensions

What are the differences between `\newdimen`, `\newskip`, and`\newlength`?

When should I use each of them? Please give me a non-trivial example for each case.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`\newlength` is the LaTeX2e version of `\newskip`. It has extra check to avoid redefinition or illegal name. In LaTeX2e, it is defined

```
\def\newlength#1{\@ifdefinable#1{\newskip#1}}
```

For example,

```
\newlength\foo % OK
\newlength\foo % redefinition ERROR!

\newlength\endbar % ERROR: \endbar is illegal command name in LaTeX2e.
% It is reserved by LaTeX kernel to define bar environment together with \bar
```

`\newskip` only allocates a new skip (glue, or rubber space) register. If you use low-level TeX command `\newskip` instead, no error message will be shown.

You should always use `\newlength` rather than `\newskip` in LaTeX.

---

`\newdimen` is another low-level TeX macro that allocates a new dimension register, it is different with `\newskip`. They have different meaning. For example,

```
\newdimen\rigidlength
\rigidlength=2pt % or \setlength{\rigidlength}{2pt}

\newlength\rubberlength % you cannot use \newdimen here
\setlength{\rubberlength}{2pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
```

Answer (score 14):

`\newlength` is LaTeX syntax and always a skip register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newskip\foo
\foo=1cm plus 1mm minus 3mm
\newdimen\bar
\bar=1cm %plus 1mm minus 3mm % not possible
\newlength\baz
\setlength\baz{1cm plus 1mm minus 3mm} 
\begin{document}
\the\foo \par
\the\bar \par
\the\baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: When should I use `\newdimen`, `\newlength` and `\newskip`?

Comment: @xport: For LaTeX high-level code use `\newlength`. Use `\newdimen` for lower-level code if you are sure that you only need a rigid dimension. `\newskip` also allows you to add stretch-amounts so the value can be a little higher or lower if required, which is useful for inter-word and inter-paragraph skips to fill the given size better.

Comment: `\newlength` tests if the command (length) already exists, `\newdimen` and `newskip` overwrite an already existing  definition