# Looking for \providelength

Tags: macros

I need a macro similar to `\providecommand`. `\providelength{\lengthName}{0.5cm}` should give me a new length if it is not existing yet. I would like to use the macro to set standard values for a TikzPicture if no desired values are given. I found the following code on the web but it is not working:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\providelength[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\@gtempa{\string#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@ifundefined{\@gtempa}%
    {\newskip#1}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \providelength{\ltest}{0.1pt}
  \the\ltest

\end{document}
```

The output of this document is

```
0.1pt
0.0pt
```

Hence, the command seems to have no effect at all. Instead, the argument is printed out. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't `tikz` parse those values, so you could just store them in a macro, no need for a length. Does't `etoolbox` provide something similar?

Comment: @daleif: I thought `etoolbox` would provide it, but it doesn't not, as far as I know.

Comment: If the length is already defined, setting it to a value might break the package that defined it.

Comment: @egreg: That is a fair statement -- if lengths are needed one should define such ones with very 'peculiar' names.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My solution assumes, that there is a `\` character at the beginning of the length register name, it is not tested for `tikz` etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{ifmtarg}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\otherprovidelength}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne
    \xdef\@gtempa{\string#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@ifundefined{\@gtempa}%
    {\newskip#1%
     #1=#2}%  Assign the 2nd argument.
    {}%
}
\makeatother



\providecommand{\providelength}[2]{%
\ifdeflength{#1}{% It is already defined!
}{% Not defined, so define it!
\newlength{#1}%
}%
\setlength{#1}{#2}%
}%

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\ProvideLength}[2][]{%
% Check, if the command is already defined, if not, then define it!
\ifdeflength{#2}{% It is already defined!
\GenericWarning{}{Warning: Length #2 already defined!!!!!!!!} % Optional
}{% Not defined, so define it!
\newlength{#2}%
}%
\@ifmtarg{#1}{%  is 1st argument empty -> do not set the length at all!
}{% Set the length to the value of the 1st argument.
\setlength{#2}{#1}%  
}% End of \@ifmtarg
}% End of \providecommand
\makeatother



\begin{document}
  \providelength{\ltest}{0.01pt}
  \the\ltest \par
% Some testing
  \addtolength{\ltest}{0.05pt}
  \the\ltest \par 

  \ProvideLength[0.17pt]{\ltesttwo}
  \ProvideLength{\lyetanotherlength} % initialized to 0.0pt if undefined before
 \the\ltesttwo \par
 \the\lyetanotherlength
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I added another command `\ProvideLength` which takes the length value as optional first argument and the length register names as 2nd argument. It will also generate a warning if the length register already exists.

I changed Simon's command to `\otherprovidelength` and added the missing 2nd argument as well as the assignment to the skip register.

Comment: @daleif: I meant I my previous comment: I once thought that `etoolbox` would have such a command, but I had to write it myself some months ago. I did not want to contradict you.

Comment: not at all, just wanted to emphasize that `etoolbox` has tool to build it. I did not formulate that comment very well.

Comment: Perhaps a typo? At the end of yur answer you say "My (optional) test results in 0.01pt 0.06pt", but your code will actually produce "10.0pt 10.05pt". Am I perhaps misunderstanding that final remark of your answer?

Comment: When compiling your solution, I get an undefined control sequence error for the providelength command. Any explanation for that? Still, a pdf is genarated with the correct output. Edit: I downloaded the newest etoolbox version, now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you explain the reason why the other version is not working more detailed? I don't get your explanation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Not really a typo, I changed my version on disk and did not update the posted version, but is now up to date ;-)

Comment: @Simon: You mean the `\providelength` command you posted in your question?

Comment: Yes. I thought your first sentence refers to my code: "This assumes, that you already use a \ character for your length register, ..."

Comment: @Simon: No, this is a misunderstanding -- I referred to my solution, that it assumes the name of the counter already contains a `\` character. I will change the description above.

Comment: @Simon: Your original command contains two logical errors: 1st: You use two arguments to `\providecommand`, but it is defined to have only one. 2nd: `\newskip` only defines a skip register, but does not set any value other than 0pt. I added another version of `\providelength` with a modified version of your command to my solution. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/what-are-the-differences-between-newdimen-newskip-and-newlength