# standalone: Outsourcing TikZ while relaxing predefined lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have one main document and two standalone files of tikz pics as given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79595/2288). I need to have `\newlength` in the main document and all the standalone files in order to be able to run any document on its own without the need to change the main document structure every single time.

However, relaxing lengths as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184993/2288) doesn't work for me. So, how can both cases be integrated to work flawlessly?

### Main Document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}% I need subpreambles to be true
\begin{document}

% I need to keep the following definitions
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{1cm}
\let\mylength\relax

\begin{figure}
  \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{myfrsttikz}
  \caption{My First TikZ picture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{mysecondtikz}
    \caption{My Second TikZ picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### First Standalone TikZ File

```
% myfrsttikz.tex %

\documentclass{standalone}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{2cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (\mylength,\mylength);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Second Standalone TikZ File

```
% mysecondtikz.tex %
\documentclass{standalone}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{5cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (\mylength,\mylength);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165318/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for referring me to this answer. I still don't quite know how to edit the standalone files accordingly after defining `\providelength` in the main document.

Comment: \let\mylegnth\relax effectively deletes the definition of \mylength.  I'm not familiar with either \includestandalone or subpreamble, but it seems you might want to wait before deleting \mylength.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to transmit definitions from the main source to other files is to use `filecontents` and `\input`.  `\includestandalone` seems like an unnecessary complication.

Main source:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{1cm}
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}% I need subpreambles to be true
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test5}% renamed
  \caption{My First TikZ picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

First standalone:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\input{data}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (\mylength,\mylength);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, in practice one will not add the `\includegraphics` until after the standalone has been run.