# A reusable newlength (no stop/break if length already defined)

Tags: macros, conditionals, lengths

Often I have separate .tikz files, which may contain stuff like `\newlength{\mytmplen}`; and given I'm not very original with names, the same statement ends up in multiple such files. Which turns out to be a problem, if I want to include all those files in a single .tex document -- then upon the second `\newlength` with the same argument, the compilation process would stop with:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \mytmplen already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 \newlength{\mytmplen}

?
```

So, I thought of devising a new newlength command, which would define the new length if it doesn't exist; but it would simply typeout a message, and go on if it does exist.

Obviously, I'd have to have a method to check if a command exists; and possibly a method to obtain the command name (e.g. `mytmplen`) from the command token (e.g. `\mytmplen`). So far, I found these posts relevant:

- [What are the differences between \newdimen, \newskip and \newlength?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/what-are-the-differences-between-newdimen-newskip-and-newlength)
- [How can I check in LaTeX (or plain TeX) whether a command exists, by name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/how-can-i-check-in-latex-or-plain-tex-whether-a-command-exists-by-name)
- [Print name of command, defined by \csname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64496/print-name-of-command-defined-by-csname)

I will be posting my solution as answer below; of course, corrections or alternative methods for solving this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer appears to work. A simpler method might consist of first `\let`-ting the length variable in question to `\relax` and then applying `\newlength` to it. Put differently, if you can't remember if a certain macro name has been used before to denote a length parameter (or anything else, really!) and if you're comfortable with (re)using it anyway, you can first `\let` it to `\relax` and then issue a `\newlength` directive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength\mytmplen
\setlength\mytmplen{10pt}
\the\mytmplen

\let\mytmplen\relax % let \mytmplen to \relax

\newlength\mytmplen % now it's safe to "re-issue" it as a length 
\setlength\mytmplen{20pt}
\the\mytmplen

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Mico - that is indeed a much simpler approach. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Until the lengths registers run out. They are a limited resource.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Is there a problem with running out of length registers if the same few ones get re-used over and over?

Comment: @Mico: TeX has 256 at most, many of them already in use. With e-TeX 32768 are available, but package `etex` should be used to make them available.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - I guess my question is trying to get at a different issue: Is there a risk of running out of registers if the same macro name, say `\mytmplen`, is repeatedly first `\let` to `\relax` and then reissued as a length register via `\newlength`?

Comment: @Mico: Each `\newlength` allocates a fresh new register, the name of the command sequence does not matter. If you can limit the code inside a group, then `\locskip` or `\locdimen` of package `etex` can be used instead. They are allocating locally and the registers are freed after the group is closed.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Many thanks for this clarification. Very helpful. Let's hope the OP doesn't have a program that has more than a couple hundred `\newlength` directives...

Answer (score 9):

Here is a `\providelength` command that will define a new length if not already defined, but also checks whether the command passed as argument has been defined with `\newlength`, in order to issue an error message if you try to use, say, `\providelength{\textit}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providelength}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}
   {% if #1 is undefined, do \newlength
    \typeout{\string\providelength: making new length \string#1}%
    \newlength{#1}%
   }
   {% else check whether #1 is actually a length
    \sdaau@checkforlength{#1}%
   }%
}

\newcommand{\sdaau@checkforlength}[1]{%
  % get the first five characters from \meaning#1
  \edef\sdaau@temp{\expandafter\sdaau@getfive\meaning#1TTTTT$}%
  % compare with the string "\skip"
  \ifx\sdaau@temp\sdaau@skipstring
    \typeout{\string\providelength: \string#1 already a length}%
  \else
    \@latex@error
      {\string#1 illegal in \string\providelength}
      {\string#1 is defined, but not with \string\newlength}%
  \fi
}
\def\sdaau@getfive#1#2#3#4#5#6${#1#2#3#4#5}
\edef\sdaau@skipstring{\string\skip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\providelength{\foo}
\providelength{\foo}
\providelength{\textit}

\stop
```

Here is the terminal output:

```
\providelength: making new length \foo
\providelength: \foo already a length

! LaTeX Error: \textit illegal in \providelength.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.31 \providelength{\textit}

? h
\textit is defined, but not with \newlength
?
```

---

A version with `expl3`, that avoids the trick for finding if the command is already a length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\providelength}{m}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1
   {
    \sdaau_providelength_check:N #1
   }
   {
    \msg_info:nnx { providelength } { making } { \token_to_str:N #1 }
    \newlength{#1}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \sdaau_providelength_check:N
 {
  \token_if_skip_register:NTF #1
   {
    \msg_info:nnx { providelength } { not-making } { \token_to_str:N #1 }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnx { providelength } { defined } { \token_to_str:N #1 }
   }
 }
\msg_new:nnn { providelength } { making }
 {
  \token_to_str:N \providelength :~making~new~length~#1
 }
\msg_new:nnn { providelength } { not-making }
 {
  \token_to_str:N \providelength :~#1~is~already~a~length
 }
\msg_new:nnnn { providelength } { defined }
 {
  #1~illegal~in~\token_to_str:N\providelength
 }
 {
  #1~is~defined,~but~not~with~\token_to_str:N\newlength
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\providelength{\foo}
\providelength{\foo}
\providelength{\textit}

\stop
```

This is the excerpt from the log file

```
.................................................
. providelength info: "making"
. 
. \providelength: making new length \foo
.................................................
\foo=\skip49
.................................................
. providelength info: "not-making"
. 
. \providelength: \foo is already a length
.................................................


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! providelength error: "defined"
! 
! \textit illegal in \providelength
! 
! See the providelength documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.47 \providelength{\textit}

? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| \textit is defined, but not with \newlength
|...............................................
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @egreg - good to have that error checking facility; cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first I looked up the definitions of `\newlength` and further using `texdef`:

```
$ texdef -t latex \newlength

\newlength:
macro:#1->\@ifdefinable #1{\newskip #1}

$ texdef -t latex \@ifdefinable

\@ifdefinable:
\long macro:#1#2->\edef \reserved@a {\expandafter \@gobble \string #1}\@ifundefined \reserved@a {\edef \reserved@b {\expandafter \@carcube \reserved@a xxx\@nil }\ifx \reserved@b \@qend \@notdefinable \else \ifx \reserved@a \@qrelax \@notdefinable \else #2\fi \fi }\@notdefinable 

$ texdef -t latex \@ifundefined

\@ifundefined:
macro:#1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax \expandafter \@firstoftwo \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi
```

So, apparently, one can get the command name from the command token, by using the stanza:

```
\edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}
```

... and then the name in `\reserved@a` (without the backslash) can be used in macros that check for macro existence by command name.

Using those definitions, I've put together this code for a reusable newlength command, called `\nnewlength`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\nnewlength#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\expandafter\@gobble\string#1} %
  \@ifundefined\reserved@a{%
    \edef\reserved@b{\expandafter\@carcube\reserved@a xxx\@nil} %
    \ifx\reserved@b\@qend %
      \typeout{  -- Not definable (1, \reserved@a): #1} %\@notdefinable %
    \else %
      \ifx\reserved@a\@qrelax %
        \typeout{  -- Not definable (2, \reserved@a): #1} %\@notdefinable %
      \else %
        \typeout{  -- Making newskip: #1}
        \newskip#1%
      \fi %
    \fi %
  }%
  {\typeout{  -- Not definable (E, \reserved@a): #1}} %\@notdefinable%
}
\makeatother

\typeout{1st pass...}
\nnewlength{\mytmplen}
\typeout{2nd pass...}
\nnewlength{\mytmplen}

\begin{document}

\typeout{3rd pass...}
\nnewlength{\mytmplen}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
...
1st pass...
 -- Making newskip: \mytmplen 
2nd pass...
 -- Not definable (E, mytmplen): \mytmplen 
(./test.aux)
3rd pass...
 -- Not definable (E, mytmplen): \mytmplen 
(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```