# Global horizontal spacing of the 'logicproof' environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, logic

I'd like to have global spacing between the statement and justification in `logicproof`. It should preserve the alignment on the justification/right-hand column. Something like this:

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicproof}

\begin{document}
I take it that...

\begin{logicproof}{0}
(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)) & premise%
\end{logicproof}

and then going...
\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

Comment: What's the difference to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359765/horizontal-spacing-of-the-logicproof-environment

Comment: I want to retain the column alignment, and control the amount of indentation, which I wasn't careful to specify in the other question. As I didn't understand your code, I couldn't work it out myself. Sorry!